# Problem with getting a value from a html table

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with getting a value from a html table. [image: This is the web HTML code]

This is the code of the part im trying to acces

```
<div class="cell el-tooltip" style="width: 108px;"> 1.07 </div>
```

Im trying to acces the value  with xpath .

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pane-bus-device-inverter']/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/div"))
```

I end up getting a error: "TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Comment: Please share code, what is happening, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

```
TypeError: init() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"
```

is cause you are missing `parenthesis ()`.

Instead of :

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pane-bus-device-inverter']/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/div"))
```

do this :

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pane-bus-device-inverter']/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/div")))
```

Also this xpath

```
//*[@id='pane-bus-device-inverter']/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/div
```

is absolute xpath, please use relative xpath or switch to css.

Relative xpath you can try :

```
//div[contains(@class,'is-scrolling-none')]//descendant::tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/div[contains(@class,'cell el-tooltip')]
```

or

```
//div[contains(@class,'is-scrolling-none')]//descendant::tbody/descendant::div[contains(@class,'cell el-tooltip')]
```

or

```
//div[contains(@class,'is-scrolling-none')]//descendant::div[contains(@class,'cell el-tooltip')]
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

You can use CSS selector as well. But I need to have page url to give you more robust locator.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that maybe you are using classes to identify a specific element, but there may be many elements using that class?

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit the post, im using xpath. Thanks for the anwser

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute values are different for each `td` so you can write a `xPath` using that.

```
//td[contains(@class,'el-table_1_column_7')]/div
```

If you want to iterate over all the `td` elements you can make this `xPath` as dynamic.

```
"//td[contains(@class,'el-table_1_column_'" + i + "')]/div"
```